# I want to read a text file, split it, and store the results in an array

Tags: java

I have a text file which has 10 fields(columns)each separated by a tab.And i have several such rows.I wish to read the text file, split it for every column, using a "tab" delimiter and then storing it in an array of 10 columns and unlimited rows.Can that be done?

Comment: Yes - as answer to your question. Have a look at CSV parser libs as hint for your homework.

Comment: Well, if they ask for it, it's probably because yes, that can be done.

Answer (score 3):

An array can't have "unlimited rows" - you have to specify the number of elements on construction. You might want to use a `List` of some description instead, e.g. an `ArrayList`.

As for the reading and parsing, I'd suggest using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), particularly:

- [`Files.newReaderSupplier`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#newReaderSupplier%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)
- [`CharStreams.readLines`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.html#readLines%28com.google.common.io.InputSupplier,%20com.google.common.io.LineProcessor%29)
- [`Splitter`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html)

(That lets you split the lines as you go... alternatively you could use `Files.readLines` to get a `List<String>`, and then process that list separately, again using `Splitter`.)

Comment: This is the output i get-Metrix.ArrayList@19821f, how can i get the rows and columns in my txt file after splitting?

Comment: @Pratik: It's hard to say without seeing your code... but if you've got a list and each element of the list is an array, you'd do `list.get(row)[column]` to get a particular row/column.

Comment: BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Documents and Settings/sg0209222/Desktop/metrices/11.3.txt"));
  String line = null;
  ArrayList<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
  while((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
     String[] row = line.split("\t");
     rows.add(row);
  }
  System.out.println(rows.toString()); // rows is a List

Comment: @Pratik: If that's printing `Metrix.ArrayList`, that suggests you're not using the built-in Java ArrayList. Why?

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
String line = null;
List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
while((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
   String[] row = line.split("\t");
   rows.add(row);
}
System.out.println(rows.toString()); // rows is a List

// use rows.toArray(...) to convert to array if necessary
```

Comment: Note that that will use the platform default character encoding, which is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: For such a trivial example, why complicate it with such matters? This is likely a homework problem and he will probably be testing with something creating in notepad.exe ... I digress. Good catch, Mr. Skeet!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to load a .txt file and store it into a array for a set amount of lines.

```
import java.io.*;


public class TestPrograms {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String conent = new String("da");
    String[] daf = new String[5];//the intiger is the number of lines +1 to
// account for the empty line.
    try{
    String fileName = "Filepath you have to the file";
File file2 = new File(fileName);
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file2);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    int i = 1;
      while((conent = br.readLine()) != null) {

        daf[i] = conent;
        i++;
    }br.close();
      System.out.println(daf[1]);
      System.out.println(daf[2]);
      System.out.println(daf[3]);
      System.out.println(daf[4]);
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.print(ioe);
    }

}
}
```